# Source code for the collectd java plugin GenericJMX

Tags: java, jmx, collectd

[Collectd](https://collectd.org/) supports writing your own plugins using Java Code.  It does this with through the [Java plugin](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Java).  I need to write a java plugin.  I figured I would look over an example, namely, the plugin [GenericJMX](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:GenericJMX).

Does anyone know where I can find GenericJMX's sourcecode?

[This repository](https://github.com/uptimesoftware/generic-jmx) seems to be related to something called Uptime, not to collectd. And, it is written in php, not Java.

Comment: This plugin does not seem to function and can only read the memory stats mbean and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/collectd/collectd/tree/master/bindings/java/org/collectd/java

BTW, I found another plugin, [JMXMemory.java](https://github.com/collectd/collectd/blob/master/bindings/java/org/collectd/java/JMXMemory.java), to be more straightforward and therefore a better example of a CollectD Java plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think that OpenTSDB plugin can help you:
[collectd opentsdb java plugin](https://github.com/auxesis/collectd-opentsdb)